# Get content between html tags with identifier inside

Tags: php, html, text, preg-match-all

I have these span tags :

```
<div>
<span style="background: url('/wp-content/themes/minimum-child/img/address.png') 0px 2px no-repeat; padding-left: 20px;">CONTENT 1</span>
<span style="background: url('/wp-content/themes/minimum-child/img/email.png') 0px 2px no-repeat; padding-left: 20px;"><a href="mailto:post@post.com">CONTENT 2</a></span>
<span style="background: url('/wp-content/themes/minimum-child/img/tel.png') 0px 2px no-repeat; padding-left: 20px;">CONTENT 3</span>
</div>
```

and I need to get the CONTENT between the spans, but I need to separate the content to single variables `$address`, `$email`, `$phone`, `$web`, etc.. It is clear, that I can use name of background images as patterns, because the names of images are still the same (address.png, email.png, etc..)

So far I think that it is necessary to use `preg_match_all` function, I have tried it already, but so far I was unsuccessful.

I tried (for getting address to `$address` variable):

```
$url="'/wp-content/themes/minimum-child/img/address.png'";
$tag='span style="background: url('.$url.')';
$matches=array();
$pattern = "/<$tag ?.*>(.*)<\/span>/";
preg_match($pattern, $htmlcontent, $matches);
$address=$matches[1];
```

Unfortunately, it is not working. Do you have any idea how to achieve it?

Comment: is it the `SPAN` content ( ie: `CONTENT_1,CONTENT_2` etc ) or the `style` attributes ('address.png' etc) you want to capture?

Comment: Hi, I need to capture CONTENT_1, etc.. pattern should be for example address.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is often said that parsing html with a regex is full of problems - so I'd opt for the simpler method of using `DOMDocument` to aid processing of the html fragment - you could then use a regex to further refine some of the results if desired perhaps.

```
$html='
<div>
    <span style="background: url(\'/wp-content/themes/minimum-child/img/address.png\') 0px 2px no-repeat; padding-left: 20px;">CONTENT 1</span>
    <span style="background: url(\'/wp-content/themes/minimum-child/img/email.png\') 0px 2px no-repeat; padding-left: 20px;"><a href="mailto:post@post.com">CONTENT 2</a></span>
    <span style="background: url(\'/wp-content/themes/minimum-child/img/tel.png\') 0px 2px no-repeat; padding-left: 20px;">CONTENT 3</span>
</div>';


$dom=new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML( $html );

$col=$dom->getElementsByTagName('span');
$keep=array(
    'style'=>array(),
    'data' =>array(),
    'email'=>array()
);

foreach( $col as $node ){
    $keep['style'][]=str_replace( "'", "", $node->getAttribute('style') );
    $keep['data'][]=$node->nodeValue;
    if( $node->hasChildNodes() ){
        foreach( $node->childNodes as $child ){
            if( $child->nodeType==XML_ELEMENT_NODE && $child->hasAttribute('href') ) {
                list($mailto,$address)=explode(':',$child->getAttribute('href') );
                $keep['email'][]=$address;
            }
        }
    }
}
echo '<pre>',print_r($keep,true),'</pre>';


/* output
   ------

    Array
    (
        [style] => Array
            (
                [0] => background: url(/wp-content/themes/minimum-child/img/address.png) 0px 2px no-repeat; padding-left: 20px;
                [1] => background: url(/wp-content/themes/minimum-child/img/email.png) 0px 2px no-repeat; padding-left: 20px;
                [2] => background: url(/wp-content/themes/minimum-child/img/tel.png) 0px 2px no-repeat; padding-left: 20px;
            )

        [data] => Array
            (
                [0] => CONTENT 1
                [1] => CONTENT 2
                [2] => CONTENT 3
            )

        [email] => Array
            (
                [0] => post@post.com
            )

    )
*/
```